# Quarkus, CDI and Transactional observer methods planned to be implemented?

Tags: quarkus

A well documented limitation of Quarkus CDI is

> BEFORE_COMPLETION, AFTER_COMPLETION, AFTER_FAILURE and AFTER_SUCCESS transactional observers are not implemented yet

Will this functionality be implemented in future releases of Quarkus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we do plan to implement transactional observers in Quarkus. There's already an open issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/2224. However, we don't have a schedule yet.